# Create System ID - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which after transforming is giving me the desired result. However, I need the idea of a Primary Key or Tracking ID to be generated.

XML:

```
<Records count="5">
  <Metadata>
    <FieldDefinitions>
      <FieldDefinition id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" name="Risk and Control Assessment ID" alias="Tracking_ID" />
      <FieldDefinition id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" name="Risk" alias="Risk" />
    </FieldDefinitions>
  </Metadata>
  <LevelCounts>
    <LevelCount id="444" guid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" count="5" />
    <LevelCount id="98" guid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" count="14" />
  </LevelCounts>
  <Record contentId="578859" levelId="444" levelGuid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" moduleId="648" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="107826" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Access Control</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107830" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Automation Strategy</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" type="6">578859</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="578887" levelId="444" levelGuid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" moduleId="648" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="107840" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Financial Oversight</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" type="6">578887</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="578891" levelId="444" levelGuid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" moduleId="648" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="578876" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">**Instance Test Case</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="534783" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">2013 HIPAA Revisions</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107836" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Executive Sponsorship</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107866" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Human Resources Management</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" type="6">578891</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="578892" levelId="444" levelGuid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" moduleId="648" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="578876" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">**Instance Test Case</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107874" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Customer Delivery</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107843" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Incident Management</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="549977" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Losses associated with customer relationships not legally perfected with adequate care</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" type="6">578892</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="578894" levelId="444" levelGuid="ed7718c6-57ea-49a4-839e-a0a4da48e8ce" moduleId="648" parentId="0">
    <Record contentId="107866" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Human Resources Management</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107853" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Performance Monitoring</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="107863" levelId="98" levelGuid="6a2fc306-1d9e-4921-b5a8-a608fdd92121" moduleId="152" parentId="0">
      <Field id="1923" guid="753702be-5b1e-4cf4-a2e8-3e7e7950c19b" type="1">Separation of Duties - Responsibilities</Field>
    </Record>
    <Field id="25675" guid="292e6d6f-0ae2-4cd6-b14b-7a5210ebbffd" type="6">578894</Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

My XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fieldDefinition" match="FieldDefinition" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <Records>
        <!-- for each leaf node -->
        <xsl:for-each select=".//Record[not(Record)]">
            <!-- replicate the tree, starting from the top -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Record[last()]">
                <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="@contentId"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Records>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:element name="Relationship_{@levelId}">
        <!-- deal with the current level -->
        <New_Tracking_ID><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></New_Tracking_ID>
        <Field_contentId>
            <xsl:value-of select="@contentId" />
        </Field_contentId>

        <xsl:element name="{key('fieldDefinition', Field/@id)/@alias}">
            <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- continue to the next lower level, branching to current leaf node only -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[descendant-or-self::Record/@contentId=$leafId]">
            <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally, my result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578859</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578859</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107826</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Access Control</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578859</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578859</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107830</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Automation Strategy</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578887</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578887</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107840</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Financial Oversight</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578891</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578891</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>578876</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>**Instance Test Case</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578891</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578891</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>534783</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>2013 HIPAA Revisions</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578891</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578891</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107836</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Executive Sponsorship</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578891</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578891</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107866</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Human Resources Management</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578892</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578892</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>578876</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>**Instance Test Case</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578892</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578892</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107874</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Customer Delivery</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578892</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578892</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107843</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Incident Management</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578892</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578892</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>549977</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Losses associated with customer relationships not legally perfected with adequate care</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578894</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578894</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107866</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Human Resources Management</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578894</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578894</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107853</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Performance Monitoring</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
   <Relationship_444>
      <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
      <Field_contentId>578894</Field_contentId>
      <Tracking_ID>578894</Tracking_ID>
      <Relationship_98>
         <New_Tracking_ID>1</New_Tracking_ID>
         <Field_contentId>107863</Field_contentId>
         <Risk>Separation of Duties - Responsibilities</Risk>
      </Relationship_98>
   </Relationship_444>
</Records>
```

What I need is to have the New_Tracking_ID to be a series of generated numbers that are sequential in nature. Preferably only to exist within Relationship_444 but that, I believe, does not matter. I've tried a few things which work but places the created ID, using position(), outside of the Relationship_444 node. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried something with the `generate-id()` function so far? (See XSL spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#misc-func)

Comment: That worked to a certain extent; I now need to see if there's any way in which I can format it.

Comment: You speak of primary keys. Primary keys only need to be unique and permanent. Why would they also need to be sequential and/or formatted? -- Note also that the ids generated by the generate-id() function will be unique **for the  currently performed transformation** only.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<New_Tracking_ID><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></New_Tracking_ID>` in the template matching `Record` you always get 1 because **`position()` returns the position of the current node in the *current node set***, not necessarily the position of the current node among its siblings.

When in your stylesheet you call

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Record[last()]">
    <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="@contentId"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

the *current node set* is the one containing all the nodes selected by `ancestor::Record[last()]`, i.e. a set containing just a single node whose position is 1.

So:

- in order to have a sequential enumeration of the "leaf" `Report` nodes, you can use *their* position (as you are already looping over them), for example passing it as an additional parameter
- to avoid another `New_Tracking_ID` element inside `Relationship_98`, don't pass the new parameter when you call `xsl:apply-templates` inside the `Record` template, and check for its value

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fieldDefinition" match="FieldDefinition" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <Records>
        <!-- for each leaf node -->
        <xsl:for-each select=".//Record[not(Record)]">
            <!-- replicate the tree, starting from the top -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Record[last()]">
                <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="@contentId"/>
                <!-- position relative to the "leaf" Record elements -->
                <xsl:with-param name="leafPosition" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Records>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:param name="leafId"/>
    <xsl:param name="leafPosition"/>
    <xsl:element name="Relationship_{@levelId}">
        <!-- deal with the current level -->
        <xsl:if test="$leafPosition">
            <New_Tracking_ID><xsl:value-of select="$leafPosition"/></New_Tracking_ID>
        </xsl:if>
        <Field_contentId>
            <xsl:value-of select="@contentId" />
        </Field_contentId>

        <xsl:element name="{key('fieldDefinition', Field/@id)/@alias}">
            <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- continue to the next lower level, branching to current leaf node only -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[descendant-or-self::Record/@contentId=$leafId]">
            <xsl:with-param name="leafId" select="$leafId"/>
            <!-- no leafPosition parameter, to avoid another New_Tracking_ID -->
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```